# Failed to run aapt dump badging - Google play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, google-play

I can't upload my application to the Play Store.

When I upload the file.apk, I recive this error:

> Failed to run aapt dump badging: W/ResourceType(17873):
>
> Bad XML block: header size 28024 or total size 1702240364 is larger than data size 2004
>
> ERROR: AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt

The application is signed with jarsigner and i used the zipalign to align this file. Also I use phonegap to create the apk.

This is the code of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      package="com.naica.enciclopedia" 
      android:versionName="1.0.0" 
      android:versionCode="1">

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true" 
/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/MeDroidTheme">
<activity android:name=".Naica" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name"android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
<intent-filter></intent-filter>
</activity>
</application><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Greetings!.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />` is nowhere to be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html). Take a look at the link I provided you and remove that from the manifest. I think that this functionnality is covered by `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`.